# Contadores no suman correctamente

Tags: java, condiciones, contador

!Buenas!

Estoy acabando un pequeño proyecto, el cual es simular un **estilo de Poker**.

Tengo **esta parte del código**, el cual me esta dando problemas:

```
public void verificarGanador(Jugador jugador1, Jugador jugador2) {

    if(jugador1.getPuntuacion() > jugador2.getPuntuacion()) {

        System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 1 HA GANADO!");
        System.out.println("Puntos J1-> " + jugador1.getPuntuacion());
        System.out.println("Puntos J2-> " + jugador2.getPuntuacion());

    }else if(jugador1.getPuntuacion() < jugador2.getPuntuacion()) {

        System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 2 HA GANADO!");
        System.out.println("Puntos J2-> " + jugador2.getPuntuacion());
        System.out.println("Puntos J1-> " + jugador1.getPuntuacion());

    }else if(jugador1.getPuntuacion() == jugador2.getPuntuacion()) {

        empate = true;

        this.cartaAlta(jugador1);
        this.cartaAlta(jugador2);

        if (jugador1.getPuntuacion() > jugador2.getPuntuacion()) {

            System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 1 GANA POR CARTA ALTA!");
            System.out.println("Puntos J1-> " + jugador1.getPuntuacion());
            System.out.println("Puntos J2-> " + jugador2.getPuntuacion());

        }else if (jugador1.getPuntuacion() < jugador2.getPuntuacion()){

            System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 2 GANA POR CARTA ALTA!");
            System.out.println("Puntos J2-> " + jugador2.getPuntuacion());
            System.out.println("Puntos J1-> " + jugador1.getPuntuacion());

        }else if(jugador1.getPuntuacion() == jugador2.getPuntuacion()){

            System.out.println("!EMPATE DE CARTE ALTA!");
            System.out.println("Puntos J1-> " + jugador1.getPuntuacion());
            System.out.println("Puntos J2-> " + jugador2.getPuntuacion());
        }
    }
}


private void cartaAlta(Jugador jugadorTest) {

    if(empate) {

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {

            if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[0])) {
                puntuacion= 1;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[1])) {
                puntuacion= 2;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[2])) {
                puntuacion= 3;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[3])) {
                puntuacion= 4;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[4])) {
                puntuacion= 5;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[5])) {
                puntuacion= 6;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[6])) {
                puntuacion= 7;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[7])) {
                puntuacion= 8;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[8])) {
                puntuacion= 9;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[9])) {
                puntuacion= 10;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[10])) {
                puntuacion= 11;
            }
            else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[11])) {
                puntuacion= 12;

            }else if(jugadorTest.cartasJugador[i].equalsIgnoreCase(Baraja.baraja[12])) {
                puntuacion= 13;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

El problema empieza cuando entra en los condicionales de "Carta alta". Los contadores no me suman, o cogen un valor que no tiene nada que ver.

La variable `empate` la tengo iniciada en el constructor como `false`.

Y esta es la `baraja`, que la tengo estática en una clase `Baraja`:

```
public static final String [] baraja = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K","A"};
```

> La idea realmente es sencilla. Si en un principio ambas manos de los
>   jugadores son iguales, se activa el empate y va hacia el método
>   `cartaAlta`y aqui, dependiendo de la carta da como valor **X** puntos
>   al contador para volver a comparar y re-decidir quien es el ganador.

Este seria un ejemplo de lo que me ocurre:

```
Jugador 1: [3][J][9][10][10] --> PAREJA

Jugador 2: [K][K][9][4][A] --> PAREJA

!EMPATE DE CARTE ALTA!
Puntos J1-> 1
Puntos J2-> 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiero algunos cambios a tu código.

Primero, un método que te devuelva el *Valor numérico* de una carta, por ejemplo:

```
private int getValorCarta(String carta)
```

No te sugiero una implementación, creo que esta parte la puedes resolver por ti mismo.

Luego, en la clase `Jugador`, un método que te devuelva el valor numérico de la carta mayor, así como ya tienes el método `getPuntuacion()`, que sería algo como:

```
private int getValorCartaMayor() {
  int resultado = 0;
  int valorCarta;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    valorCarta = getValorCarta(cartasJugador[i]);
    if (valorCarta > resultado) {
      resultado = valorCarta;
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Finalmente, entonces, comparar que jugador tiene la carta mayor, se convertiría en algo trivial, parecido a esto:

```
// el if del else está de más, si no es ni menor, ni mayor, 
// la única opción que queda es que sean iguales
// no quito el if para que te ubiques dentro del código.
} else if(jugador1.getPuntuacion() == jugador2.getPuntuacion()) {
    empate = true;
    if (jugador1.getValorCartaMayor() > jugador2.getValorCartaMayor()) {
      System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 1 GANA POR CARTA ALTA!");
    } else if (jugador1.getValorCartaMayor() < jugador2.getValorCartaMayor()) {
      System.out.println("!EL JUGADOR 2 GANA POR CARTA ALTA!");
    } else {
      superEmpate = true;
      System.out.println("¡EMPATE DE CARTE ALTA!");
    }
```

Finalmente, con esto, sospecho que quisieras cambiar la implementación de tu método `getPuntuacion()` a algo como (si es que no es ya así):

```
private int getPuntuacion() {
  int resultado = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    resultado += getValorCarta(cartasJugador[i]);
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Me funciona perfecto de esta forma. Muchas gracias, que maquina.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema está en la función `cartaAlta`. No está devolviendo nada, está editando una variable `puntuacion` pero es la misma variable las dos veces que ejecutas la función, por lo que el valor se sobreescribirá. Luego ni si quiera usas esa variable `puntuacion`.

Comment: En la función `cartaAlta` edito el valor de puntuación para que se reinicie a ese valor. Entonces cuando entra en el primer empate, se activa el `boolean` y utilizo el método de `cartaAlta` para que verifique la carta que es igual a la de **baraja** y dependiendo cual sea, edita la puntuación. Y después, con el `getPuntuacion` obtengo el nuevo valor. Esa es la idea que tengo.

Comment: El problema es que en ningún caso se está editando la variable miembro `puntuacion` de la clase Jugador. Quizá lo que quieres es algo así como `jugadorTest.puntuacion = 1;` o `jugadorTest.setPuntuacion(1);`. En cualquier caso creo que la solución de @jachguate es lo mejor a largo plazo, aunque requiera más cambios.